# Force redirect a URL in WORDPRESS on mobile

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to use a plugin to force redirect this URL: http://arubacontests.com/LaCabana25

to this URL:
http://zosoci.al/5858/lacabana25

I use two different plugins:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

But they just wont redirect my URL on mobile version.

Is there any way we can do some FORCE CODES to force wordpress to redirect a certain URL on mobile and tablets or so???

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me on my android phone, maybe you are seeing a cached version on your phone?

[Clear cache on android](http://www.accessc.com/articles/clear-history-cookies-cache-android.html)

[Clear cache on iphone](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache-on-an-iPhone)

Comment: yup, I tested it on 2 phones and tested in my browser as well.  You my friend don't have an issue.

Comment: What kind of phone are you using mate? Are you using chrome or firefox?

Comment: I am on Android with Chrome, what about you?  I can't imagine this is an issue between devices though, redirects are pretty standard across the board

Comment: Yeah my boss told me its not working. He is using an android phone with a chrome browser.

Comment: it is definitely working, maybe your boss is typing the URL wrong

Comment: yeah. even on mobile its not working. Tried to type exactly the same but it wont just work.

Comment: did u try to clear your cache?  Do you have FTP access to get a copy of your .htaccess file and show me the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed force a redirect based on the browser's MIME type which is different for mobile. You can try the following which will apply only for connections from mobile devices:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arubacontests\.com\/LaCabana25 [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

RewriteRule ^ http://zosoci.al/5858/lacabana25 [R,L]
```

The above would be applied in an .htaccess file for the website. If you'd like to set it up in the theme code itself, you can do this for example by using the screen resolution of the agent in JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
window.location = "http://zosoci.al/5858/lacabana25";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

This will need to be placed in the code for the page you would like to redirect from, or you can put it in the index page so it would apply for the initial hit on the page.

Comment: Is this can be applied via WP theme?